# Swift_SmtpTransport phalcon

Tags: php, dependency-injection, phalcon, swiftmailer

I'm trying to load SwiftMailer on Phalcon 3 with the Dependency Injector and I get an error about the Swift_transporter Service.

> **Phalcon\Di\Exception:** Service '\Swift_SmtpTransport' wasn't found in the dependency injection container

I would like to know how I can load the Swift_SmtpTransport service in the dependency injector, **without composer**. I know that composer can solve this problem easily, but I wonder if there are other options.

In my service.php file I added the next lines:

```
$di->set('mailer', function(){

$mailer = new Manager([
    'driver'   => 'sendmail',
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'viewsDir' => $this->config->application->viewsDir . 'emails/',
    'from'     => [
        'email' => 'notify@website.com',
        'name'  => 'Company Team'
    ]
]);

return $mailer;
```

});

Then i call the service with the next lines:

```
$this->mailer([
        'to'      => 'email@test.com',
        'name'    => 'First and Last Name',
        'subject' => _('Welcome to my website'),
        'body'    => [
            'view'   => 'welcome',
            'params' => [
                'name' => 'First Name',
                'link' => $this->url->get('users/activate/?email=email@test.com&activation_key=******')
            ]
        ]
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I understand how it works the Phalcon Incubator. If someone installs the Incubator without composer must consider that some libraries in the incubator needs external libraries. For this reason if you install Incubator by cloning the Github repository and you don't execute composer update, you have to load all dependencies of the external library one by one.

Comment: Or just register whole dir or namespace with phalcon loader :)

Comment: i dont have any vendor folder in my structure, how should i resolve the same issue

Answer (score 0):

In phalcon 3.0 There were added new method do phalcon loader called `loadFile`. Just use it with `swift_required.php` path

Comment: Hi Juri! Thanks for your reply